# TestNG @BeforeClass doesn't run from super class if it not an immediate parent

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Say class inheritance is like C -> B -> A where A being the topmost super class.

```
  class A {
     @BeforeClass
     void setUp() {
       //some stuff
      }
    }

    class B extends A {

    }

    @Test
    class C extends B {
      //running this class DOES NOT invoke setUp() from A.
    }
```

I have @BeforeClass testng annotation in class A. And I only annotate class C with @Test. Now, I expect that while running class C it should execute @BeforeClass annotated method in super class A. But it is not.

But it runs when I move the @BeforeClass annotation to class B.

Any ideas?

Right now, the work around is to reannotate in class B as well.

```
  class A {
     @BeforeClass
     void setUp() {
       //some stuff
      }
    }

    class B extends A {
      @BeforeClass
      void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        //some stuff
      }
    }

    @Test
    class C extends B {
      //running this class invokes setUp() from only B.
    }
```

Note: The issue is not there if there is only two levels of inheritance to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have the same method name between A and B.

When TestNG is looking for configuration methods, it won't find the annotation on the `setUp()` method of `B`.
In every case, you'll have to annotate your method in `B` because TestNG is not able to find configuration methods without annotation.

You can keep the work around you use, or you can rename one configuration method. `setUp` is no more mandatory.

But we can suppose it is an issue which can be solved by TestNG too. So, you should open a ticket on the project: http://github.com/cbeust/testng

Comment: I was not clear in my original description. Made an edit now to explain the problem.

Comment: Which version of testng do you use? Could try the latest one (6.9.9)?

Comment: That worked with 6.9.9. I was using 6.9.6 earlier. Thanks juherr!

Answer (score 2):

When using groups for your tests you can sometimes get this behaviour as well.
In that case one thing you can do to make sure the parent setup method is  annotated to use `alswaysRun = true`, like so:

```
  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void parentSetupClass() {

  }
```

Source https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

> For before methods (beforeSuite, beforeTest, beforeTestClass and
> beforeTestMethod, but not beforeGroups): If set to true, this
> configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs
> to. For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true,
> this configuration method will be run even if one or more methods
> invoked previously failed or was skipped.

Comment: It works for me. Adding `alwaysRun=true` to super class.

Answer (score -2):

The `@BeforeClass and @AfterClass` are implicitly static method and doesn't support inheritance .

When you want to refer to class A `@BeforeClass and @AfterClass`  method you need to provide call for the methods from class B `@BeforeClass and @AfterClass` as follows . It is a concept of method hiding in Java .

```
public class A {
     @BeforeClass
     public static void setUp() {
       System.out.println("A");
      }
}
public class B extends A {
      @BeforeClass
      public static void setUp() {
        A.setUp();
        System.out.println("B");
      }
}
public class C extends B {
      //running this class invokes setUp() from B.
        @Test
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("test in C");
        }
}
```

The output would be as follows .

```
A
B
test in C
```

Comment: It's totally wrong, you are confusing JUnit and TestNG.